# In Python - How to count the occurrences of the word “price” in each row of the column “content”?

Tags: python, text, nlp

[data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyof6.png)

I hope the data is visible. It is a small textual data frame with row and columns. I need to count the occurrences of a specific word like "price" in each row of a column named "content".

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: Welcome to SO. We expect some minimal effort to solve the problem and an explanation of how the solution is deficient. It is best if you provide minimal examples of the data and the expected result(s) along with your written descriptions. Please read [ask], [mre], and the other links found on those SO help pages.

Comment: Pandas has wonderful documentation: [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

First, let me help you display the dataframe:

| date | title | content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/10/2010 | one thing | this price is a low price |
| 10/9/2010 | two things | price is high |
| 10/8/2010 | three things | high price is higher price |

You can write a python function to get the count of a specific word in the sentence of the **content** column.

```
def word_count(sentence, query_word):
    word_list = sentence.split()
    return word_list.count(query_word) 

if __name__=="__main__":
    sentence ='high price is higher price'         
    print(word_count(sentence, 'price'))
```

Or if you want count all words, try `Counter`

```
from typing import Counter

sentence ='high price is higher price'
c = Counter(sentence.split())
print(c['price'])
print(c.most_common())
```

Comment: Thank you so much  @liijqhs for helping. This looks great. Next time I will make sure to display the table as you did. Ideally, I am trying to collect the output into a new column. And each row of the new column would have a count of the occurrences of the word _price_